# Get data from Webpage that looks like Javascript into Java?

Tags: java, javascript, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the data from http://www.futbol24.com/Live/?__igp=1&LiveDate=20141104 and get the time, home team and away team for each match on that page.

I have tried using jSoup - but now realise that the page seems to load javascript after the page loads... Is there any way I could still get this data?

Cheers
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with Jsoup.

You can try with Selenium and/or:

PhantomJS:

[http://phantomjs.org](http://phantomjs.org/)/

and Pjscrape:

http://nrabinowitz.github.io/pjscrape/

For example with Phantomjs you can scrape with:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');// File System Module
var args = system.args;
var output = './temp_htmls/test1.html'; // path for saving the local file 
page.open('http://www.futbol24.com/Live/?__igp=1&LiveDate=20141104;rpp=50;po=0;dct=PS;D=OSHA-2013-0020', function() { // open the file 
  fs.write(output,page.content,'w'); // Write the page to the local file using page.content
  phantom.exit(); // exit PhantomJs
});
```

Here we have opened the page using PhantomJs and then saved locally. After you can use Jsoup or Beautiful Soup to scrape it.

Good luck!

Comment: Providing some code examples and explanations using the libraries you mentioned would make this a much better answer.

Comment: Thank you, Antonio. I will give this a go tonight and see how I get on :)

Comment: @RobEves  It was a pleasure to help you :D!!